# Error deploying JSF app in Glassfish

Tags: jsf, netbeans, glassfish

I used to deploy a JSF+Primefaces app in a Glassfish server without any trouble. Recently I upgraded my NetBeans version. I haven't had any problems with the most of the applications after that. But with one of them when I tried to do the deployment, it failed and this was the error message:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document
>   'jar:file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/[name-of-the-application]/WEB-INF/lib/javax.faces.jar!/META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml':
>   null. Please see server.log for more details.

It seems like all is ok with the project (cleans and build well), but the error keeps appearing. This is the environment I'm using:

- NetBeans 7.3.1
- JSF 2.2 (Mojarra)
- GlassFish Open Source Edition 3.1.1 (build 12).

PS: When I try to do the deployment with Glassfish 3 bundled in NetBeans, this is the error:

> SEVERE: Error during deployment : class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.PersistenceUnit Scanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK JSF 2.2 applications deploy on GlassFish v4, not sure if they can deploy on Glassfish v3.x

Comment: @Luiggi: They can. Servlet 3.0 is minimum requirement. GF3 is Servlet 3.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Unable to parse document 'jar:file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/[name-of-the-application]/WEB-INF/lib/javax.faces.jar!/META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml

The path to the taglib file suggests that you shipped JSF 2.2 along with the webapp inside its `/WEB-INF/lib` instead of upgrading GlassFish itself. As GlassFish 3 itself ships with a JSF 2.1 implementation out the box, you need to instruct it to not load it in order to avoid version conflicts. You didn't state anywhere that you were doing that, so I guess that this is the whole cause of your problem.

Glassfish itself already ships with JSF bundled which get by default classloading precedence over the one bundled in the webapp. You basically need to tell Glassfish to use the webapp bundled JSF instead.

In order to achieve that, edit the `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` to add the following two lines.

```xml
<class-loader delegate="false" />
<property name="useBundledJsf" value="true" />
```

If the file does not exist create it, you can find a sample xml file [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaql.html). and add the two lines from above inside the `<glassfish-web-app>` tag.

GlassFish will then suppress its own bundled JSF from loading and rely on webapp-bundled JSF.

Alternatively, if you have full admin control over Glassfish, you can also copy the `javax.faces.jar` file from JSF 2.2 into the `/glassfish/modules` directory, hereby replacing the old one, in order to upgrade it from JSF 2.1 to JSF 2.2 so that it get applied on all webapps.

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza, @BalusC, thanks for your answers. Finally I resolved the problem downgrading JSF to 2.1.25 since I don't need any new feature from JSF 2.2. With your answers you resolved indirectly another problem I had, it was that JSF 2.1 did behave like hell in Glassfish 4 these seems to be versions' deployment issues. I still have to learn a lot about deployments. Thanks again!

Comment: Forgive me for using the thread, have the same problem. @BalusC Where in the glassfish-web.xml should it be? I can not get it to work